# how to pass SMS to the default SMS application based on criteria

Tags: android, gps, sms

I am looking to make an app that checks for the speed of the device (if driving etc) and if it is under the pre-set threshhold, it will pass the SMS to the standard receiving device with the standard notification. If the criteria fails (moving too fast). I want it to still pass the SMS, supress the notification, and auto-send a reply to the sender.

Currently, this is what I have just for receiving and sending:

```
    package biz.midl.drivereply;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

public class MainActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {

    int MAX_SPEED = 1000; //will have a change method later

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  //context cannot be resolved
    Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (lastKnownLocation.getSpeed() > MAX_SPEED)
        {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();  //intent cannot be resolved

            if (extras == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            abortBroadcast();

            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
            SmsMessage msg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);

            String origNumber = msg.getOriginatingAddress();            
            String reply = "The user is busy. Try again later.";

            SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(origNumber, null, reply, null, null);           
        }
    }
}
```

I showed the errors after the lines with comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are only interested in the speed when an SMS is received, you do not need to continually monitor your location and speed. In this case, your BroadcastReceiver should be implemented to start upon an `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast. To do this, register your receiver in your manifest, like so:

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver"> 
    <intent-filter android:priority="999"> 
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then, in the `onReceive()` method, simply check the last known location for its speed, and reply if necessary:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (lastKnownLocation.getSpeed() > MAX_SPEED)
    {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if (extras == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        abortBroadcast();

        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage msg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);

        String origNumber = msg.getOriginatingAddress();            
        String reply = "The user is busy. Try again later.";

        SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(origNumber, null, reply, null, null);           
    }
}
```

In the above example, the receiver's priority is set to the maximum (999) so it will receive the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast first. Then, the broadcast is aborted if the speed is greater than your defined speed limit, and a reply is sent to the sender. Otherwise, nothing is done, and the broadcast will continue on to other receivers registered to get it, like the platform SMS app.